# Implementing remove function for element tree element

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I am trying to remove an element from an XML tree. My attempt is based on the example that I found in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file):

> ```py
> for country in root.findall('country'):
>     # using root.findall() to avoid removal during traversal
>     rank = int(country.find('rank').text)
>     if rank > 50:
>         root.remove(country)
>
> tree.write('output.xml')
> ```

But I'm trying to use the `remove()` function for a string attribute, not an integer one.

```py
for country in root.findall('country'):
    # using root.findall() to avoid removal during traversal
    description = country.find('rank').text
    root.remove(description)
    
tree.write('SampleData.xml')
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: remove() argument must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not str.

I ultimately added another element under `country` called `description` which holds a short description of the country and its features:

```xml
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
        <description>Liechtenstein has a lot of flowers.</description>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N" />
        <description>Singapore has a lot of street markets</description>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W" />
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E" />
        <description>Panama is predominantly Spanish speaking.</description>
    </country>
</data>
```

I'm trying to use the `remove()` function to delete that `description` attribute for all instances.

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2081835). It will help us recreate your issue.

Comment: Please don't delete the previous content, as my answer refers to it.

Comment: Sorry! Will add it back.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, in your code you are passing a string as argument, not a node:

```py
    description = country.find('rank').text
    root.remove(description)
```

This is not what happens in the correct examples. The one with the integer does this:

```py
    rank = int(country.find('rank').text)
    if rank > 50:
        root.remove(country)
```

Note that `country` is removed (a node), not `rank` (an int).

It is not clear what you want to do with the description, but make sure to remove a node, not a string. For instance,

```py
    description = country.find('rank').text
    if description == "delete this":  # just an example condition
        root.remove(country)
```

Or, if you just want to remove the "rank" node and keep the country node:

```py
    ranknode = country.find('rank')
    if ranknode.text == "delete this":
        country.remove(ranknode)
```

As you mention you have actually a `description` *element* (you call it an attribute, but that is confusing), you can target *that* element instead of `rank`:

```py
    descriptionnode = country.find('description')
    if descriptionnode.text == "delete this":
        country.remove(descriptionnode)
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot! I ran a couple of tests cases and it has worked. Not too sure how to apply this to whitespaces now. For example, let's assume there are excessive whitespaces in the .xml file:

for country in root.findall('country'):
    whitespace = country.find('').text
    if whitespace == '  # whitespaces ':
        root.remove(country)

Comment: If you mean there is white space in the *content* of an element, then you shouldn't delete the node, but replace its text. If however you speak of white space between elements -- that is not meaningful to the XML structure and you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Last question, sorry! When you show how to remove just the "rank" node and not the entire "country" node, I'm confused about ranknode.description. Let's say in the example.xml file above I added an additional tag called description that gives a short little summary of the country's features i.e. <description>Panama has a lot of flowers</description>. Would the code then to just remove the description be:

for country in root.findall('country'):
 description_node = country.find('description')
 if description_node == 'Panama has a lot of flowers':
             root.remove(description_node)

Comment: Yes, did you try it?

Comment: I did, it is not working

Comment: I'm confused on what '.description' of ranknode.description is

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In my answer that should be `ranknode.text`.

Comment: Tried that as well but I get the following error:
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: That probably means that you are trying to delete a node that is not in the tree. If you cannot make that work, please provide sample XML (a minimal one) and your failing code for *that* sample. That way we can reproduce it.

Comment: Just uploaded the sample code and my code!

Comment: Fixed an issue in my answer. You need to call `remove` method on the direct parent of the node that you pass as argument.